# How mysql count birth month each class and columns are classes

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

The data in mysql db like this and show a result in Datagrid in WPF

```
 ---------------------------
 class student_ID birthday
 A     1          2000/1/1
 A     5          2001/4/1
 B     2          2000/1/12
 C     3          2001/8/5
 .     .          .
 .     .          .
 Z     1000       2000/12/2
---------------------------
```

I know use group by and with rollup can select subtotal and total

but I have no idea to do like statistic table

```
----------------------------------
 month\class    A    B    C ... Z
 JAN            1    2    3 ... 0
 FEB            0    5    6 ... 7
 .              .    .    .
 .              .    .    .
 DEC            4    8    6 ... 1
----------------------------------
```

One of my way is using case each month,but if the problem becomes statistic date not month, 365 columns is impossible.

What is google way to solve the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
select
  monthname(birthday),
  sum(case when class = 'A' then 1 end) as a,
  sum(case when class = 'B' then 1 end) as b,
  -- add the other 24 letters here
from my_table
group by monthname(birthday)
```

Comment: but if the class is not fix, should i use loop to do it?

Comment: Then you need a real table "pivot". I think MySQL doesn't support those.